# Apache Camel FTP can not catch file created events on remote FTP folder

Tags: spring, spring-boot, ftp, apache-camel

I'm trying to use Apache Camel FTP to consume files which be pushed to a FTP folder. The route and connection to FTP server for Camel context is ok but I can not get file create event to processing when file be pushed to FTP folder.
Here is my code and logs:
First is a part of my pom.xml for camel (I'm using camel 3.0.1 version) :

```
<!-- Listen FTP folder -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.camel.springboot/camel-spring-boot-starter -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.camel/camel-core-starter -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-core-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.camel.springboot/camel-ftp-starter -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-ftp-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.camel.springboot/camel-jacksonxml-starter -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-jacksonxml-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.camel.springboot/camel-jackson-starter -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-jackson-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.camel.springboot/camel-rabbitmq-starter -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-rabbitmq-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

The RouteBuilder to initialize camel consume :

```
package xx.listener.route;

import org.apache.camel.LoggingLevel;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.component.jackson.JacksonDataFormat;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import xx.listener.common.model.ddXMLModel;

@Component
public class DataRouter extends RouteBuilder {
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Initialize camel route...");
        JacksonDataFormat jacksonDataFormat = new JacksonDataFormat();
        jacksonDataFormat.setInclude("NON_NULL");
        jacksonDataFormat.setPrettyPrint(true);

        from("ftp://user@localhost:21/ftp/files?password=abc@123&move=.done&moveFailed=.error")
                .log("${body}")
                .unmarshal().jacksonxml(ddXMLModel.class)
                .marshal(jacksonDataFormat)
                .log("${body}")
                .to("rabbitmq://localhost:5672/test_camel?username=root&password=123456&queue=camel.queue&autoDelete=false").end();
    }
}
```

My log when starting application :

```
Initialize camel route...
[INFO ] 2020-12-22 14:21:24.522 [main] SpringBootRoutesCollector - Loading additional Camel XML routes from: classpath:camel/*.xml
[INFO ] 2020-12-22 14:21:24.522 [main] SpringBootRoutesCollector - Loading additional Camel XML rests from: classpath:camel-rest/*.xml
[INFO ] 2020-12-22 14:21:24.530 [main] SpringBootCamelContext - Apache Camel 3.0.1 (CamelContext: camel-1) is starting
[INFO ] 2020-12-22 14:21:24.531 [main] JmxManagementStrategy - JMX is enabled
[WARN ] 2020-12-22 14:21:24.747 [main] RabbitMQComponent - The old syntax rabbitmq://hostname:port/exchangeName is deprecated. You should configure the hostname on the component or ConnectionFactory
[INFO ] 2020-12-22 14:21:24.755 [main] SpringBootCamelContext - StreamCaching is not in use. If using streams then its recommended to enable stream caching. See more details at http://camel.apache.org/stream-caching.html
[WARN ] 2020-12-22 14:21:24.772 [main] JacksonDataFormat - The option autoDiscoverObjectMapper is set to false, Camel won't search in the registry
[INFO ] 2020-12-22 14:21:24.897 [main] SpringBootCamelContext - Route: route1 started and consuming from: ftp://user@localhost:21/ftp/files?move=.done&moveFailed=.error&password=xxxxxx
[INFO ] 2020-12-22 14:21:24.902 [main] SpringBootCamelContext - Total 1 routes, of which 1 are started
[INFO ] 2020-12-22 14:21:24.904 [main] SpringBootCamelContext - Apache Camel 3.0.1 (CamelContext: camel-1) started in 0.372 seconds
[INFO ] 2020-12-22 14:21:24.908 [main] ListenerApplication - Started ListenerApplication in 2.979 seconds (JVM running for 4.169)
```

I connect to my FTP server, change to the files directory and push a sample xml file to this folder and nothing is happen in my application console. I haven't got any log more.

I've also tried add route to Camel Context in application main class. But I got the same result.

```
CamelContext camelContext = new DefaultCamelContext();
        try {
            camelContext.addRoutes(new DataRouter());
            camelContext.start();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            camelContext.stop();
        }
```

What is wrong with my code. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue be fixed by added `passiveMode=true` to ftp uri to allow login to ftp server

Answer (score 0):

Just 2 ideas because nothing happens (no files read, no errors)

- Has the user permission to see the files?
- Are the files under `[userHome]/ftp/files`?

The second point is because Camel FTP path is always relative. Therefore the user's home path, i.e. the directory where the user lands after the ftp login, is the starting point of the path.

And finally: try to increase your log level to DEBUG